# How to upgrade AngularJS 1.6 to Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

I have read Angular's official document for upgrading from 1.x to version 5. But I unable to achieve **ngUpgrade**.

Can anybody help to resolve this issue or help me how to proceed?

Old Project is in **AngularJS 1.6** and I am using **[ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/)** for routing mechanism.

Below is the sample code for the of the controller,

> heroController:

```
myApp.controller("heroController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    // Controller Code
}]);
```

> index.cshtml code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

I have a wrapper of MVC for existing application. Now I want to migrate to newer version of Angular(Version 5 and upcoming versions).
Since the existing application have a lot of controllers, directives, services factories, thus I want to first ngUpgrade thereafter I will start migrating component wise.

NOTE:
I am not using any build tools to bundle js files, I am using MVC's bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you can do,

(i) Best way is to rewrite the application.

(ii)Or migrate each module wise. You can read on How to migrate from the following blog.

https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b

Comment: Thanks, but in blog the application is written in ES6 class based standard, and bundling is happening using webpack. Whereas I have used function based approach and bundling is happening through mvc bundles. and adding to that ui-router is also breaking.

Comment: So you might have to switch to another router: https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid is capable of dealing with Angular1 and Angular 2 routes. Migration from Angular1 to Angular2 **is** an major endeavour, but it paid off for us.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same request, from a client, some time ago. After searching the internet for a quick fix for this found this guide. It has multiple steps, takes it one at a time. It is a lengthy process, but at least each step is described:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/migrate/

Hope it helps

P.S. ngUpgrade needs this first: replace the `ng-app` directive with `angular.bootstrap.`

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs and Angular are diffrent, in the sense that all Angular is a complete rewrite of AngularJs.
In other word AngularJs are all version of Angular 1 While Angular is version 2 upword.